# Is it possible to reduce the height of appbar in windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

I want to make a sleek looking thin appbar. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting Height and MinHeight work for me:

XAML:

```
<AppBar Height="25" MinHeight="25"> ... </AppBar>
```

HTML/CSS:

```
.win-appbar.sleek {
    height: 25px;
    min-height: 25px;
}


<div id="sleekAppBar" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBar" class="sleek"
    data-win-options=""> ... </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's think about this differently.

Why keep the AppBar the same size? The reason is, your application will visually align to the rest of the Windows 8 ecosystem. I am not saying yo can't change the AppBar; I'm just saying you had better have a good reason.

How to customize the AppBar? Here's my whole blog on the topic: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/10/walkthrough-windows-8-appbar-you-might.html

Comment: Hi Jerry. How do you display SecondaryCommands programmatically?